# The compiler gives no warning on returning local pointer

Tags: c

I am using code blocks with GCC compiler. In the code below, compiler gives warning while returning local reference but no warning on returning local pointer though both are same thing. Why ?

I understand these variables are local and will be destroyed as soon as control returns from the function. De-referencing these would result in undefined behavior.

```
int *check(int j)
{
    int *q;

    q= &j;
    return q; // No warning
    //return &j; // Warning
}
```

Comment: If you don't use the return value the program stays defined. Compiler is doing you a favor by warning you, it doesn't have to.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, my installation of gcc (5.4.0) produces the expected warning.

Comment: Because the compiler isn't smart enough. You shouldn't rely on the compiler being smart enough.

Comment: As long as you don't use the return-value in order to access the pointed memory address, no harm is done.

Comment: Please look at my answer below. It does not show how to get a warning but it shows an interesting I would say issue with GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, because warnings are optional.

Second, this code

```
int *q
...
return q;
```

doesn't return a the address of a local variable directly.  You wrote the explicit code that made the pointer point to an address that becomes invalid when the function returns.  No compiler can be expected to save you from that.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Compiler doesn't check where the pointer is pointing to therefore no warning. But it sees the address while returning reference.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew I would have to disagree.
According to [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

> -Wno-return-local-addr
>   Do not warn about returning a pointer (or in C++, a reference) to a variable that goes out of scope after the function returns.

Edit: I redact my earlier claim. Turns out GCC does disappoint me. Apparently that error only works if you directly return something that will be cleared from the stack. If you store it in a temporary variable GCC does not check that even though it has more then enough information to do so just my checking if the pointer leads to some address between `%EBP` and `%ESP`

Here is some code I made to test it real quick to confirm that GCC doesn't check. If you run this with `-Wall` it produces no error however if you return `&val` it will produce two warnings (one for the return one for j not being used). I feel like GCC should recursively check that my returned pointer stays in scope rather then just checking the immediate value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int * myFunc(int val){
        int *j;
        j=&val;
        return j;       //Should not work val goes out of scope
}

int someFuncToClearMyStack(int a, int b, int c){
        int d;
        int e;
        d=a+b+c;
        e=c-b-a;
        d=d-e;
        return d;
}

int main(){
        int *i;
        int j;
        i=myFunc(10);
        printf("%i\n",*i);
        j=someFuncToClearMyStack(3,4,5);
        printf("%i %i",*i,j);
        return 0;
}
```